# Conference venues

Tags: soft-question

Most of the conferences I've learned about essentially by word of mouth.

Is there any website listing prominent economics conferences? I'm interested in Economic Theory conferences mostly, but feel free to comment with any helpful listing Economics conferences.

Answer (score 4):

You may find [conference maker](https://editorialexpress.com/cgi-bin/conference/listconfs.cgi) useful, it lists upcoming conferences in economics/finance.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of any comprehensive list of theory conferences. But here are some usual suspects in North America:

- [Econometric Society Meetings](https://www.econometricsociety.org/meetings/future-meetings)
- [AEA Meetings](https://www.aeaweb.org/conference/)
- [Canadian Economic Theory Conference](https://www.economics.utoronto.ca/conferences/index.php/cetc/index/schedConfs/archive)
- [Game Theory Society Conferences](http://www.gametheorysociety.org/conferences/)
- [Stony Brook Game Theory Summer Festival](http://www.gtcenter.org/?page=Conference.html)
- [Midwest Economic Theory and International Trade Conference](https://myweb.uiowa.edu/rriezman/)

Some institutes/departments (e.g. [BFI](https://bfi.uchicago.edu/events/economic-theory-conference-iii), [Columbia](http://econ.columbia.edu/columbia-conference-economic-theory), [Cowles Foundation](http://cowles.yale.edu/conferences/theory-sum17)) would have periodic but irregular theory workshops. However, presentations in these events are usually by invitation only.